# RSA encryption between Erlang and Python

Tags: python, encryption, erlang, rsa

How can encrypt data in erlang and decrypt it in python? I have wrote this codes but does not work. How can fix it?

Erlang code:

```
PrvKey = [257, 77181119504409699204797322144340611322502523292227043692039327666381749008487, 77131657261414365158890407156927969457179535804176721705182844017912686753873].
PubKey = [257, 77181119504409699204797322144340611322502523292227043692039327666381749008487].
Enc = crypto:rsa_private_encrypt(<<"hello">>, PrvKey, rsa_pkcs1_padding).
B64 = base64:encode_to_string(Enc).
```

Now the value of B64 is `"ITSqh/3jlijZR6qxeGjoutUlP5Bvzy+MjULqnY3CSxg="` and i send it to python and trying to decrypt it.

Python code:

```
import rsa
import base64
pub = PublicKey(77181119504409699204797322144340611322502523292227043692039327666381749008487, 65537)
prv = PrivateKey(77181119504409699204797322144340611322502523292227043692039327666381749008487, 65537, 77131657261414365158890407156927969457179535804176721705182844017912686753873, 64921744597321522210744827947572972024591, 1188833109509413311172008266846274857)
b64 = base64.b64decode("ITSqh/3jlijZR6qxeGjoutUlP5Bvzy+MjULqnY3CSxg=")
rsa.decrypt(b64, prv)
```

Here I have an error in python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py", line 232, in decrypt
    raise DecryptionError('Decryption failed')
rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed
```

What is my code problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given [how asymmetric cryptography usually works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Description), you should probably:

- Encrypt with public key (i.e. `PubKey`).
- Decrypt with private key.

Good luck!

EDIT>

In erlang, you use a public key exponent `257`, which is wrong. Use `65537` instead.

This should work:

```
PubKey = [65537, 77181119504409699204797322144340611322502523292227043692039327666381749008487].
Enc = crypto:rsa_public_encrypt(<<"hello">>, PubKey, rsa_pkcs1_padding).
B64 = base64:encode_to_string(Enc).
```

and

```
prv = rsa.PrivateKey(77181119504409699204797322144340611322502523292227043692039327666381749008487, 65537, 77131657261414365158890407156927969457179535804176721705182844017912686753873, 64921744597321522210744827947572972024591, 1188833109509413311172008266846274857)
b64 = base64.b64decode("BlqO1VeQJmvqqIYZJx+7QXEJzSb8XuIvVD+v665NkH0=")
rsa.decrypt(b64, prv)
```

Comment: I'v done that. Here is my error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py", line 227, in decrypt
    decrypted = core.decrypt_int(encrypted, priv_key.d, priv_key.n)
AttributeError: 'PublicKey' object has no attribute 'd'`

Comment: Leave the private key in python -- it was _probably_ correct.

Comment: Your public key exponent seems wrong, will update the answer